# Как использовать метода lower?

Tags: python

Здание было следующее: *Выводить номер недели принимая от пользователя день недели.*

Я написал следующий код

```py
day = input('Введите день недели:')

if day == 'понедельник' or day == 'Понедельник':
    print('День № 1')
elif day == 'вторник' or day == 'Вторник':
    print('День №2')
...
```

преподаватель сказал, что задача решена правильно, но нужно сделать её через метод lower, покопался в сети, посмотрел про него( он записывает все символы в нижнем регистре, но не могу применить её в данной задаче.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в текстовом виде. Никаких скриншотов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот ещё один вариант решения :)

```py
days = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье']
day = input('Введите день недели: ').lower()

if day in days:
    print(f"Номер дня недели: {days.index(day) + 1}")
else:
    print("Введите день недели!")
```

То, что в квадратных скобках - это список (массив, другими словами): более подробно прочитать можно [здесь](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/spiski-python-funkcii-i-metody-python-list).

`if day in days` - это проверка, находится ли пользовательский ввод в нашем списке (массиве) значений. В `days` лежат наши дни недели, а в переменной `day` то, что вводит пользователь. Например, если юзер напишет `ЧеТвЕрГ`, то с помощью функции `lower()` ввод сконвертируется в нижний регистр и получится *четверг*. И как видно, в списке `days` есть наш день недели *четверг*.

Функция `index()` это одна из большого количества функций, которые можно применять к спискам. `index()` возвращает номер элемента в списке. То есть мы ищем, каким по счёту находится введённый пользователем день в массиве `days`.

Например:

```py
days = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье']
day = 'четверг'

print(days.index(day))  # 3
```

Вернет нам число 3, потому что элементы в списках всегда начинаются с нуля. 0 - первый элемент, 1 - второй, и так далее.

Более подробно можно прочитать [здесь](https://dev-gang.ru/article/metod-listindex-v-python-9n2owwgsnr/).

Comment: А как бы это построить не с помощью массива,а с помощью цикла for???

Comment: Что конкретно с помощью цикла?

Comment: или лучше скажи,что значат кв. скобки и дейс индекс в принте,а также if day in days,буду благодарен)

Comment: Обновил ответ :)

Answer (score 3):

Так как вам не известно в каком регистре введут данные целесообразно сразу привести `input()` к нижнему регистру. и после этого сравнивать ответ:

```
day = input('Введите день недели').lower()

if day == 'понедельник':
    ...
```

Comment: Парень,спасибо,ты мне очень помог